# Are dupes being redirected for non-logged in users?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically redirect anonymous user from unanswered duplicate question to corresponding answered version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/automatically-redirect-anonymous-user-from-unanswered-duplicate-question-to-corr)

I try to go to [my question here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8633/is-it-true-that-your-heart-skips-a-beat-when-you-sneeze) with is a duplicate of another question.

When I try to go to the question when I am **not** logged it, it ***automatically*** redirects me to the questions that it was the duplicate of.

Was this always the case?

[Link to chat discussion about this](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/920742#920742)

Comment: @JeremyBanks hmmmm, shouldn't users be informed that they were redirectd?

Comment: I agree, that would be a good idea; do it like like Wikipedia with a link back to the original near the top.

Comment: @JeremyBanks [My feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127432/155556)

Comment: Your original question is listed in the _Linked_ section on the right side of the page (but it also redirects).

Comment: @M.Babcock haha oy... infinite linkage

Comment: The ironic part is that this question was closed as an exact duplicate.

Comment: @JXPheonix it only helps my cause ^_^

Comment: many original posters will find this redirection away from their work highly offensive! This gotta stop!