# On redirected duplicates, show linkback to original

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

This is related to the comments on my previous post: [Are dupes being redirected for non-logged in users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127431/155556)

---

Can we please put a linkback to the original question on all posts that were redirected (somewhat like we do with migrated questions) so that new users, who are not normally on this site, understand what happened.

---

Side-note:

Also, when the user is redirected, make it so the linked questions on the side (which are **all** duplicates) have the `noredirect` set. As you can see [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/6151/651) and if you click on the linked question when you are **not** logged in, it takes you back to the same place where you were -- aka a loop.

Comment: Missing `noredirect` on the linked dupes for anon users is a bug, since it just brings them back to the page they are on.

Comment: @cdeszaq that may be. I just did not want to make so many meta posts on the same subject, I put them all in one

Comment: That's why I just dropped a comment, rather than an actual post :)

Comment: Isn't this link already present in the "linked questions" sidebar on the right?

Comment: @JeffAtwood but it redirects in circles because it does **not** have the noredirect in the link.

Comment: The side-note appears to have been fixed. The main request has not been implemented though.

Answer (score 9):

I agree. It's confusing to be taken to a different page than you saw in the search results, with potentially none of the words you searched for. (Duplicate questions are often better written—that's why they appear higher in the search results). A header informing 'you have been redirected' would resolve that objection. Wikipedia does this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125245/168589

It's also duplicitous to show different pages to search engine crawlers than to anonymous readers. This is one reason people dislike Quora.