# Cancel a reopen request

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-reopen

This is a feature request: in case I voted for reopening a question which was a good question (TMO) which was unnecessarily closed, then the OP changed it. 
Now, the current version of the question is something I wouldn't want to reopen - but there isn't any way I could find to cancel my original reopen request.

Comment: I imagine we can count this under [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

Comment: Just trust everyone else *not* to follow your lead. The vote will expire after some time.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek it makes sense to connect between these issues, but I believe that it will need to open a separate "FR/bug".

Comment: @alfasin If the ability to retract close votes was declined, I'm pretty sure they're not going to implement retracting reopen votes

Comment: @BoPersson if I were, I wouldn't be posting here this question :) but seriously, same like you can cancel up/downvote by clicking again on the arrow (within an acceptable time-frame), I think that it could be a good idea to allow reviewer "undo" closing/opening flag.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek the fact that this request remained open since 2009 doesn't mean it has been rejected. The most voted answers actually agree that such a feature will be useful, and since SO is a community-driven website, I would expect operations to "listen to the people" :)

Comment: @alfasin It's tagged [meta-tag:status-declined]. This means that it *has* been rejected.

Comment: ohhhh.... my bad! thanks for the responses everyone!

Comment: That's NOT a duplicate, oh well...

Comment: The question was initially incorrectly tagged as duplicate of retract-close request. Since that retract-close request was completed, but retract-reopen still is not available. Please reopen this question to track it separately.

Comment: @Glorfindel this question was asked 1 year before the other one, and this was one was boo'ed while the other one became popular even though it's the same question <palm-face>. Anyways, since it _is_ the same question I guess it's fine that you closed it as dup. I'll try to not take it personally... :)))

Comment: I'm not sure why this one didn't gain attraction either. Perhaps because it was closed too soon, as a duplicate of a question which didn't was a duplicate after all? (Somebody pinged me in chat about this today, that's why I merely changed the duplicate. I didn't look at the timestamps, just at the general answers & score.)

Comment: @Glorfindel I guess popularity is also a matter of reputation and my reputation in meta is very humble compared with the person who opened the other one. Anyways I appreciate you taking a look even though this one is pretty old (would be awesome to have this feature regardless of which FR was asking for it)!