# Chat feed bot for new questions posted a link to a question from 2015 likely due to a new comment

Tags: support, chat

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36129346#36129346

The linked question is from 2015, and the chat bot is supposed to only post links to new questions.

The only new thing there was a comment: [Is this an animation error, or just bizarre character design?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18621/is-this-an-animation-error-or-just-bizarre-character-design#comment53548_22436)

Seems like a bug. Also I'm getting "An error occurred submitting the question." on the anime's meta and I suspect all SE metas could be having problems at the moment.

---

It's not a bug I was just logged out from that tab and once I logged in I could see that it was a closed dupe post and it would redirect you to the primary duplicate without warning. False alarm.

Comment: No, the question is from 10 hours ago. Where did you see it's from 2015?

Comment: This is a pretty confusing piece of functionality meta people. By all means close this question as a dupe, but without that it's good to have around. The issue is easily reproducible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That question, itself, isn't from 2015 - it's from 10 hours ago (when I looked).

[image: asked10hoursago]

However, the question was closed as a [duplicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v6FO.png), so when you go there not signed in, it [*redirects* you to the duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/automatically-redirect-anonymous-user-from-unanswered-duplicate-question-to-corr), which is from 2015.

[image: asked2015]

So you're just getting confused, because when you click on the link it redirects you to a [question from 2015](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18621/is-this-an-animation-error-or-just-bizarre-character-design), but [the question that's in the feed](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/39470/art-style-choice?noredirect=1&lq=1) was new.

I think that this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: Good catch! Yes, this is by design, always was. (redirection.)