# Weird migrated post

Tags: support, migration

The [post was asked 4 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301519/i-have-trouble-with-requests-with-required-auth) by [@oleksandrm1608](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/371515/oleksandrm1608) and marked as [migrated]:

> [image: migrated]

Clicking on it redirects me to to the [post asked more than 3 years ago](https://stackapps.com/questions/4573/my-app-has-to-be-published-first-but-its-still-under-development).

What’s going on here?

[Timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/301519/timeline) doesn’t add more new information. Only about the post have been migrated by Shog9.

Comment: Probably merged... but I was wondering this, too.

Comment: @Catija timeline says about migration only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have an account at Stack Apps? (Doesn't seem like it.) Because the question has no answers and was marked as a duplicate, anonymous users will be automatically redirected to the duplicate target (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125807/323179)). (The fact that it was migrated doesn't affect anything actually.)

You can use [this link](https://stackapps.com/questions/7618/i-have-trouble-with-requests-with-required-auth?noredirect=1&), which ends in `?noredirect=1` to see the question without being redirected.