# Sometimes, search leads to a question that was marked duplicate

Tags: discussion

It is annoying to get directed to a question that has been closed as a duplicate, while the original's answers thoroughly solve the problem.

On the other hand, sometimes the duplicate has answers that could add depth to the original, which get (more or less) lost by closing it.

Comment: What's actually wrong with that? That's exactly how the system is intended to work, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't get directed to a duplicate; the search results show that it's a duplicate so if you click on it, it will show the (closed) question's details, not the original. Other behaviour would actually be confusing; what if I *do* want to view the closed question, e.g. to edit it or change the duplicate target?

If you don't want duplicates in your search, add `duplicate:no` to your query.

Or you could log out; anonymous users are [automatically redirected from a question closed as duplicate to the original question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125220/295232).