# How to check the source of a question flagged as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, redirection

I was writing [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295178/how-to-non-interactively-install-tzdata) and got to the end of it.

I then realized that there is a possible solution in [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556385/how-can-i-install-apt-packages-non-interactively) - and it indeed worked.

I nevertheless posted my question and immediately marked it as a duplicate (the idea being that someone may stumble upon a different wording that may help to redirect to the answer I pointed to). What I see from my side is:

---

[image]

---

I made a wrong manipulation (with the help of my cat) and ended up opening an incognito window and pasting the URL of my question there: `https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295178/how-to-non-interactively-install-tzdata`

To my surprise, it is redirected to the answer I set as the "first" one when creating a duplicate for mine.

Indeed, there is a `301` redirection:

```
# curl -v https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295178/how-to-non-interactively-install-tzdata
*   Trying 151.101.65.69:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to askubuntu.com (151.101.65.69) port 443 (#0)
(...)
> GET /questions/1295178/how-to-non-interactively-install-tzdata HTTP/2
(...)
< HTTP/2 301
< cache-control: private
< location: https://askubuntu.com/questions/556385/how-can-i-install-apt-packages-non-interactively
```

**Is there a way in that case to see (for someone else than me) the content of my question (marked as duplicate)?**

Comment: Add `?noredirect=1` to your question URL. It is normal for duplicate questions being redirected for anonymous users. See [Automatically redirect anonymous user from unanswered duplicate question to corresponding answered version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125807/289905).

Comment: Your cat might signal you that it want a duplicate cat.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard: I will mark her as duplicate and get rid of her - as this is the wife and children's cat, not mine. We just co-live in the same house and compete for the laptop.

Comment: @user289905: the change is from 2012... It took me some time to realize that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed this is intentional for anonymous users. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125807/289905) by SE staff for details.

What would be the value of users reading your question, only to find out in the end the answer is to be found elsewhere?

Your question isn't without value. Seeing that your wording didn't result in you finding the other question (with the answer), and hence others who use the same search terms will end up at your question. We can now redirect them to where the answer is to be found, which uses different terminology.

Comment: I understand the value of ultimately landing at the first answer (the one the duplicate points to). It is just that I remember having seen plenty of cases where there was a `[duplicate]` postfix to the question, with the duplicates (possibly several). But maybe, as @user289905 mentioned, this is for anonymous users.