# Deleted duplicates should show the duplicate target(s)

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions, redirection

Some questions on Stack Exchange sites get deleted, but they are still linked from various other places on the internet. I will use [this deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331325/lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn-n) from Mathematics Stack Exchange as an example.<sup>1</sup> If the deleted question was a duplicate, it might be useful for people who followed a link to that question to *see at least the duplicate target.*

*Possible ways to find duplicates.* This is not a problem for 10k+ users, who can see deleted posts - they see the content of the post and also the duplicate. The duplicate target could also be [found using SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1344785/duplicate-target-of-the-given-post), since the Postlink table contains also the links for deleted posts. In some cases, Wayback Machine could help with finding [some version of the question](http://web.archive.org/web/20150925041341/https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331325/lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn-n). Also the link of the form `/questions/linked/qid` [works for deleted questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1331325), too and that also reveals the duplicate target. But I'd guess that a user who is not very familiar with Stack Exchange would probably not think of these possibilities immediately.

There already exists a way in which anonymous users are redirected to duplicate targets - here is the corresponding feature request, which is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): [Automatically redirect anonymous user from unanswered duplicate question to corresponding answered version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125220).

**Feature request:**

- Make the redirect for anonymous users to the duplicate target work also in cases when the question is deleted.
- For low-rep users (which do not have the privilege to see deleted questions) show somewhere that the question was a duplicate and add a link to the duplicate target. (If there are multiple duplicate targets, show all of them.)

EDIT: To have at least some data on numbers of such questions, here are some SEDE queries. (Take them with a grain of salt, since this is my very first attempt to make a multisite query and I do not have much experience with SQL. Still, I hope that the result should be at least approximately correct.) Here is [the number of deleted duplicates](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1346156/number-of-deleted-questions-which-are-duplicates-multisite) per site. This query calculates [what percentage of deleted questions are duplicates](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1346163/number-of-duplicates-among-all-deleted-posts-multisite) - it runs a bit longer. Maybe you might also want to check the [list of deleted duplicates on some specific site](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1346153/list-of-deleted-posts-which-are-duplicates).

---

<sup>1</sup>I am pretty sure that there exist many deleted questions which are linked from somewhere. The specific case which lead me to thinking about this was when I [searched for limit of n^(1/n)](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Csqrt%5Bn%5Dn%24&p=1)
in Approach Zero, that is a math-specific search engine which is [rather popular on Math Stack Exchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/announcing-a-third-party-search-engine-for-math-stackexchange). I got as the top result [this deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331325/lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn-n) from Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: Typically, the general advice is to not delete duplicates unless they add *nothing* in the way of searching for and finding the target question.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog On Mathematics, nearly every recent closed question is deleted. At least that's how it seems.