# My question is not shared in LinkedIn when I copy the link

Tags: discussion, support, bug, share-this

One of my questions was closed for being a duplicate. When I share it to [dev.to](https://dev.to) it's shared. The problem is when I try to share it via `copy link` to LinkedIn, it fetches the duplicate question instead  of my question.

**Note:** **if i copy the url from browser search bar it's okay.. but problem appear when i the copy url from share dialog box...(in my google chrome browser)**

**Screenshot of question closed as duplicate**

[image: Screenshot of question closed as duplicate]

**Screenshot of share dialog**

[image: Screenshot of share dialog]

**Shared question on dev.to**

[image: Screenshot of closed question on dev.to]

**Why is the duplicate question shared in LinkedIn instead of my question?**

[image: Screenshot of duplicate target of the closed question on linkedin.com]

Answer (score 9):

You should check what happens if you open the link (`https://stackoverflow.com/q/65686515/11554326`) in a private browser window (or in another browser where you're not logged in). Yes, it redirects you to the original question (the question which your question has been marked as a duplicate of). This is a consequence of [Automatically redirect anonymous user from unanswered duplicate question to corresponding answered version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125220/295232).

To avoid this, don't use the `/q/` short link generated by the 'Share' button, but the full link of the question, and append `?noredirect=1` to the URL, like this: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65686515/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript-dynamically?noredirect=1`

Comment: it will confuse  user .. when user go details page he will see different question title ..it's not logical...

Comment: Better than not being familiar with Stack Exchange's concept of 'duplicates' and not finding the right answer to their problem ...

Comment: @noor Have you actually tried it with the noredirect link? When I do, it shows the correct question in the preview. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEDr7.png So... I don't think the confusion you're worried about will exist if you just repost this link.

Comment: `?noredirect=1` code is working ...

Comment: @Catija if  i copy the url from browser search bar it's okay.. but problem appear when i the copy url from share dialog box...(in my google chrome browser)